# Unity3d or WebGL: Where should I go?

Tags: unity, webgl

I am interested in making a simple 3D game this summer, and I'd prefer if it were playable in a browser. My choices I am considering are Unity and WebGL. Currently I have no experience in either. But I have taken an introduction course to OpenGL. As well I will later be taking a course that will use Unity. I have some C# experience, but no web background.

The factors I'm considering are ease to learn and the penetration each has. I know Unity games can be uploaded to Kongregate, which seems like a pretty big deal if I made a game that would be somewhat successful. But of course that may not be the case at all.

Which way should I lean? Personally I think learning WebGL would be the easiest transition, but I am not sure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unity is by far the easier option and thus the one I would recommend. Especially considering you have no previous experience developing a 3D game, you want to pick the simplest solution possible in order to complete your game in such a short time frame.

---

That said, there is one significant advantage to WebGL in your situation, so this advantage may be enough to sway your decision. Working with WebGL will teach you a lot more about how 3D graphics and 3D renderers work under the hood. If you are planning to be an engine programmer then you will need to learn that stuff.

Take a look at this link, because it is very useful for you to see in evaluating which technology you wish to use: http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217

Notice that after 16 lessons it's still nowhere near a complete game.

Comment: I totally agree. WebGL is just a technique to have accelerated 3D graphics in the browser, but it's as far from a game engine as OpenGL is. You'll have to implement tons of stuff just for the basics, heck even to get some 3D models on screen. Unity will let you create a game right from the start.